# How to detect image to text using camera for mobile app

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

[I want to build a mobile app to archive something like this on video below but I dont have any idea how to start from... I need a suggest for which language to use for build. I have a projeect but I need to understand how can I do something like this.

What I need to study to do something like this one for mobile app(multiple plateform).
which language(Python, React native)?][1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjieLydWxc4&t=117s

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a Google or YouTube search for "OpenCV" and "opencv licence plate recognition" will give you a host of tutorials and programs for you to work on. My favourite two are : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMQvcWBx1fE and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tZrzluaiNI (from Murtaza). You can use Python, C++, Java with the OpenCV library.